# Turning off cell broadcast messages in Ice Cream Sandwich

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, cell-broadcast

The phone is a stock HTC One X.

The settings menu does not include a checkbox to enable/disable CB messages. They just keep popping up.

**Update**: Halfer already gave the link to the wikipedia article about CB, which should explain it in more detail than I ever can. What it means to me is that I get location information as I move around in town.

The screenshot here shows the checkbox for this feature on what I believe is Gingerbread:

[image: Screenshot]

**Update 2**: And this is the extremely boring message. This particular one just shows the carrier name, so it's even more useless and annoying than if it were showing location information:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but: what is a "cell broadcast message"?  What do they look like?

Comment: @offby1 I haven't heard about them either. Could you share a Screenshot/description?

Comment: I think these have been around for years - on non-smart phones also - but depend on the carrier. I think the idea is that the network works out roughly where you are via tower triangulation, and sends local info or traffic reports. I always turned them on out of curiosity, but (in the UK) never received anything `:(`. Aha, [here's a reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_Broadcast).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After some investigation and asking around, I have been told that these settings might be under `Settings -> Call -> Other Call Settings`, and indeed they were.

However, the owner of both a stock Samsung Galaxy S3 and an ICS updated Galaxy S2 told me that those two had the CB settings under `Messages -> Settings`.

I have not been able to find out which one of these two the default location is. It is possible that HTC has moved them.

What I have found out is that other manufacturers (Sony is one example I've come accross) are also placing CB settings under general settings rather than messaging settings, so there might not be a one-size-fits-all answer for this question.

Answer (score 2):

On S3, open up SMS/Text Messaging.

Press the Menu key - bottom left of phone.

Press 'Settings'.

Scroll towards the bottom of the screen.

'Cell Broadcast Activation' will be about 4 items from the bottom of the menu list.

Uncheck/Remove tick.

Bingo - no more Cell Broadcasts!

Answer (score 2):

On HTC ONE X you should go to

*phone → [options button] → settings → cell broadcast*

or

*settings → call → cell broadcast*

Answer (score 1):

Settings -> Phone-call -> Other call settings -> Close CB messages

Answer (score 0):

Just go to a messages, go to menu, scroll down and uncheck CB.