# Turning off cell broadcast messages in HTC One X Plus

Tags: settings, cell-broadcast

I have been receiving about 50 flash sms a day, with my service provider name TIM RS 51, from the number 50. As I read here, it might be a issue with activating and deactivating cell broadcast on the phone. However, I could not find the path suggested for the deactivation (Setting/Call/Other Call Settings). The option does not exist on this path. Any help?

Comment: Eliana, could you please add the information what Android version your device is running (the name of the device might be useful as well)? Those settings appear on different places, depending on Android version and sometimes even on device. You will find this information in *Settings->About phone* usually.

Comment: Depending on your Android version, either a duplicate or at least related: [Turning off cell broadcast messages in Ice Cream Sandwich](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24039/16575)

Comment: Some more digging: My *LG Optimus 4X* has it nowhere in its options, but it has an additional app pre-installed ("Cell Info"). Also, some other places to check include [this XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1946265), an [issue at google code](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=41539) (about not being able to turn it off), and a [video at Youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juLMhR_Ijls).

Answer (score 1):

I show the setting under

```
Settings | Wireless & networks | More... | Cell broadcasts
```

with three options to choose from:

1. Show extreme threats
2. Show severe threats
3. Show AMBER alerts

(Android 4.1.1 / Galaxy Nexus)

Comment: I cannot find that on my Optimus 4x (Android 4.0.3). Could you please add which Android version you refer to, Al? I mean, I wouldn't wonder if that again is a special "LG cleanup" (the Optimus also misses the detailed battery usage stats with the bars for network, wifi, screen on, awake)...

Answer (score -1):

It's `Settings->Call-> *uncheck* Cell broadcast -> *click* OK to the confirmation question`.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no checkbox or option about cell broadcast under settings/call. I cant find this option anywhere on the phone, specially not under Settings/Call/Cell broadcast. Thanks anyway, do you have anyother idea?...Android version is 4.1.1 and phone model is htc one x plus.

Comment: That does not resemble the option under Android 4.1.1 - that looks more like Gingerbread or earlier....