# Change Cell Broadcast alarm

Tags: cell-broadcast

Lately whenever a missile is fired upon us, I receive cell broadcast alert about it.
In my area of living the city alarms are working loud anyway but the cell broadcast sound is extremely alerting and is over stressing my 3 years old kid.

I looked in the menu (Settings -> More -> Cell broadcasts) but and I found I can make it sound for only 2 seconds (instead of four).

I would like to keep the cell broadcast but change the tune. any ideas how can I do that?

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: Possible settings/configuration is mentioned here - http://android.stackexchange.com/q/24039/35612

Might not cover your version of android but several different locations for the settings are mentioned in the answers. Reading most it seems to just toggle on/off, not actually configure?

Comment: So now it even reached the Negev, oy! More hints in [other questions tagged `cell-broadcast`](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cell-broadcast). B'hazlacha!

Comment: Related here: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/157567/9897